# Vue 3 - differences between reactive value return - toRef and computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Good afternoon. I have a reactive state in one of my composable:

```
const userState = reactive({
  email: 'test@test.com',
  name: '',
  ...other
})
```

and I want to return the email property. This is how I thought to return it:

```
return {
  email: readonly(toRef(userState, 'email'),
  emailComputed: computed(() => userState.email)
}
```

but in that case I don't understand the difference between returning it as `readonly`+ `toRef` and `computed`, since it looks they keep the reactivity outside the composable.

Any difference I am missing about?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion when you return a variable from a `composable`, that means you want to work with that variable as an output of composable in your **components**. So when you return it as [readonly](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#readonly), that means you don't want to change it during other operations in the component and if you change that **Vue** create warning for you. But when you return it as [computed](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#computed) that means you want to have the value of your main variable (here called `userState`), but also **if** needed you change it in your component. Here I posted the codes of my component and composable to determine the above sentences clearly:

> component code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ emailComputed }}</p>
    <p> {{ email }} </p>
    <button @click="changeEmail">change email</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
/* importing composable */
import {useReadOnly} from "../composables/codeReadOnly";
import {reactive} from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
   
    const { email, emailComputed } = useReadOnly();

    const changeEmail = function () {
      /* uncomment the line below and comment second line */
      // ----------------------------------------------------
      // emailComputed.value = "new-email@email.com";
      email.value = "new-email@email.com";
    }

    return {
      emailComputed,
      email,
      changeEmail
    }

  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

> composable code:

```js
import {reactive, computed, toRef, readonly} from "vue";
export function useReadOnly() {
    const userState = reactive({
        email: 'test@test.com',
        name: "",
    })

    return {
        email: readonly(toRef(userState, 'email')),
        emailComputed: computed({
            get: () => userState.email,
            set: (val) => {
                userState.email = val;
            }
        })
}
}
```

In the above code you can change the value of `emailComputed` by clicking the button, but you **can not** change the value of `email` in your main component. That is the difference I could understand, but maybe there are other differences also that I don't know.